# Возможно ли сделать код для отслеживания изменений сайта 24/7?

Tags: бот, мониторинг

Я разработал очень интересную стратегию для ставок на спорт, которая в большинстве случаев оказывается выигрышной. Но проблематично постоянно мониторить сайт букмекера в поисках и ожидании игры, результаты начала которой будут удовлетворять условия тактики.
Можно ли создать бота, который будет автоматически в реальном времени проверять сайт, и найдя подходящую ставку, уведомить об этом? В идеале подрубить этот код на телеграмм бота, который будет присылать нужные уведомления-сигналы.
Это для меня важно-видеть полную статистику ставок, чтобы оценить рабочая техника или нет.
Я сам в программировании 0, но ради такого мне не жалко потратить и пол года, чтобы научиться базе, достойной, чтобы написать такой код.

Comment: можно, но так как вы в программировании 0, то нельзя. Да и затея ваша проигрышна, бросайте это дело. В казино выигрывает только казино

Comment: Сама реализация такой идеи возможна, но т.к. навыков нет, то проще на аутсорсинге заказать.(Парсер сайта + тг-бота)

Comment: @ArchDemon казино может и да. Но ставки на спорт-статистика, аналитика и психология.

Comment: @иван я же сказал, что готов изучать язык с нуля ради этой идеи. Её не осуществят лучше меня, даже на заказ. Я как понимаю, тут пайтон лучше всего подойдет

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/31177 - вот выбери язык для парсинга (Perl), для бота-используй питон, и прочитай книгу - "Изучаем регулярные выражения" Бен Форта, так же тебе нужно будет изучить клент-серверное взаимодействие, веб-сокеты и т.п. а там уже с чем столкнешься

Comment: @ИванПавлов спасибо. Как понимаю, мне придется 2 языка учить?

Comment: @Марк чел дело не в языках, а в технологиях и теории взаимодействия кода. А так да скорее всего 2 языка, ну плюс json html css javascript для понимания парсинга